# Set Gradle custom task inputs and outputs

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, gradle-task

I am writing a Gradle plugin in Kotlin, adding a custom task.

How do I go about declaring the task's inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide getter properties with annotations as follows:

```
@get:OutputDirectory
protected val outputDir by lazy {
    // expression that evaluates to the output directory
}

@get:InputFiles
protected val inputFiles by lazy {
    // expression that evaluates to your inputs
}
```

Therefore you will have to import these 2 classes at the top of your Kotlin file:

```
import org.gradle.api.tasks.InputFiles
import org.gradle.api.tasks.OutputDirectory
```